# Is there a more efficient way to convert double to float?

Tags: c#, performance

I have a need to convert a multi-dimensional double array to a jagged float array.  The sizes will var from [2][5] up to around [6][1024].

I was curious how just looping and casting the double to the float would perform and it's not TOO bad, about 225µs for a [2][5] array - here's the code:

```
const int count = 5;
const int numCh = 2;
double[,] dbl = new double[numCh, count];
float[][] flt = new float[numCh][];

for (int i = 0; i < numCh; i++)
{
    flt[i] = new float[count];
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        flt[i][j] = (float)dbl[i, j];
    }
}
```

However if there are more efficient techniques I'd like to use them.  I should mention that I ONLY timed the two nested loops, not the allocations before it.

After experimenting a little more I think 99% of the time is burned on the loops, even without the assignment!

Comment: And 225µs is too slow for you?

Comment: If you got many (and I mean maany) doubles to convert, try processing this over multiple CPUs using the .NET 4.0 TPL (Task Parallel Library).

Comment: 10 elements and 5 allocations taking 225µs sounds very long to me.

Comment: Just a small comment, if you want to measure your performance you should use higher array sizes, when you tell me that your code performs as good as 225µs for a [2][5] md-array I really have no idea of how good is that, specially also without knowing your specs...

Comment: @Steve I know that 224µs seems fast, but everything' relative, right? :)  My data set is not large enough to warranty TPL i this case, but that's for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will run faster, for small data it's not worth doing `Parallel.For(0, count, (j) =>` it actually runs considerably slower for very small data, which is why that I have commented that section out.

```
double* dp0;
float* fp0;

fixed (double* dp1 = dbl)
{
    dp0 = dp1;

    float[] newFlt = new float[count];
    fixed (float* fp1 = newFlt)
    {
        fp0 = fp1;
        for (int i = 0; i < numCh; i++)
        {
            //Parallel.For(0, count, (j) =>
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            {
                fp0[j] = (float)dp0[i * count + j];
            }
            //});
            flt[i] = newFlt.Clone() as float[];
        }
     }
  }
```

This runs faster because double accessing double arrays `[,]` is really taxing in .NET due to the array bounds checking. the `newFlt.Clone()` just means we're not fixing and unfixing new pointers all the time (as there is a slight overhead in doing so)

You will need to run it with the `unsafe` code tag and compile with `/UNSAFE`

But really you should be running with data closer to 5000 x 5000 not 5 x 2, if something takes less than 1000 ms you need to either add in more loops or increase the data because at that level a minor spike in cpu activity can add a lot of noise to your profiling.

Comment: Right-on, this is just what I was looking for.  Is it me, or does anyone else get warm-fuzzies when you have an opportunity to use pointers in .Net? ;)

Comment: A trick I used which is worth noting is to use a local pointer variable rather than the fixed pointer, I have no idea why but there's actually a performance improvement in doing so. Something to do with accessing fixed pointers having an extra check to make sure they're still valid or something perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

In your example - I think you dont measure the double/float comparison so much (which should be a processor internal instruction) as the array accesses (which have a lot of redirects plus obviousl.... aray delimiter checks (for the array index of bounds exception).

I would suggest timining a test without arrays.

Comment: You make a good point, and with such a small data set it is difficult to know where most the time is being spent without introducing artificial delays with profiling overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use also Lists in your case you could use the LINQ approach:

```
List<List<double>> t = new List<List<double>>();
//adding test data
t.Add(new List<double>() { 12343, 345, 3, 23, 2, 1 });
t.Add(new List<double>() { 43, 123, 3, 54, 233, 1 });
//creating target
List<List<float>> q;
//conversion
q = t.ConvertAll<List<float>>(
        (List<double> inList) => 
        {
            return inList.ConvertAll<float>((double inValue) => { return (float)inValue; });
        }
     );
```

if its faster you have to measure yourself. (doubtful)
but you could parallelize it which could fasten it up (PLINQ)

Comment: Thanks, but data set is tool small to realize the performance benefits

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think that you can optimize your code much more, one option would be to make your code parallel but for your input data size ([2][5] up to around [6][1024]) I don't thing that you would profit so much if you would even have any profit. In fact, I wouldn't even bother optimizing that piece of code at all...

Anyway, to optimize that, the only thing that I would do (if that fits in what you want to do) would be to just used fixed-width arrays instead of the jagged ones, even if you would waste memory with that.